# Disable Resharper on a Project/Namespace level?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I don't want resharper to analyze my Test Project which has all my unit tests and mspec specs... It doesn't like them? Is there a way to turn off resharper on a project/namespace level?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Goto Reharper-options, settings, and press the 'advanced'-button. There you can enter files and folders that are skipped during the analysis. Should work, when your unittest have their own solutions/folders.

From their [online help](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/) under
Solution-Wide Analysis --> [Reference: Code Inspection Settings:](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Settings.html)

> Opens the Skip Files and Folders dialog box, allowing you to compile the list of files and folders that should be excluded from solution-wide analysis. See Solution-Wide Analysis for details.

Comment: so the downside of this is that is disables all my unit test runners

Comment: I see :/ but they are still visible in the "Unit Test Explorer", where you can start them, too